# Hot Reloading on GraalVM

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, hot-reload, spring-boot-devtools, dcevm

I've recently upgraded from OpenJDK 8 to GraalVM 20.1.0 (OpenJDK 11.0.7). Does anyone have any ideas how to implement hot class reloading (or at least web asset redeployment).

- Spring-Boot-Devtools doesn't pick up the changes.
- HotSpotAgent (DCEVM) has a JDK11 versio that you can replace your JVM with, but it's not GraalVM (and won't have the Polyglot features)
- JRebel (which    I have a license for, doesn't support GraalVM)

Is that it? Surely not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRebel does support GraalVM, you can see the press release here: https://www.jrebel.com/blog/jrebel-2020-2-adds-support-java-14

If you are struggling with setting up JRebel with your GraalVM you should email them at support@jrebel.com and they can help you out.

Comment: All I needed to do was re-import the gradle project into IntelliJ and it worked!